# Receiving data from php curl to another php file

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send data from one php file on a webserver to another webserver using curl, however I am unsure how to access the data that was sent to the second webserver for it to do the work. I was able to access this data before using the $_POST array however now that curl is being used to send the data I am no longer able to use that for some reason. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to access the data?

```
function post_to_url($url, $data) { 
  $fields = '';
  foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
  } 
  rtrim($fields, '&'); //DL: ugh. 
  $post = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data)); 
  curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); 
  curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  $result = curl_exec($post); 
  curl_close($post);
}
```

That is the code that I am using for the curl post itself, here is the receiving end $username = $_POST['email'];

Comment: Post us your current code if possible

Comment: curl can't do anything your browser can't... just because it's curl doesn't make the data be any different from any other http request... if the curl request doesn't have anything in $_POST on the other end, then it's something YOU'RE doing with curl, not curl itself.

Comment: Make sure you are specifying POST as the method used by cURL when sending data to the server.

Comment: The POST option is set but I have noticed that the remote server that the curl is POSTing to doesnt seem to be running the script at all. I've set it to email me on execution but im not getting any email from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using curl make sure you POST:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array());
```

Comment: The POST option is set but I have noticed that the remote server that the curl is POSTing to doesnt seem to be running the script at all. I've set it to email me on execution but im not getting any email from it.